# Openpyxl (Python library) can not fill color to excel

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to fill cell color of Excel file by using Openpyxl library.
I succeed to fill color in the past, but now I can NOT.
Do you have any recommend solution for me?

- Python: Ver 3.11.3
- Openpyxl: Ver 3.1.2
- My code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Create a new pattern fill with a blue background
fill = PatternFill(start_color='0000FF', end_color='0000FF', fill_type='solid')
fill_b1 = PatternFill(fgColor='0000FF', fill_type='solid')
fill_c1 = PatternFill(bgColor='0000FF', fill_type='solid')

# Fill cell A1 with the fill color
cell = ws['A1']
cell_b1 = ws['B1']
cell_c1 = ws['C1']

cell.value = ('A1')
cell_b1.value = ('B1')
cell_c1.value = ('C1')

cell.fill = fill
cell_b1.fill = fill_b1
cell_c1.fill = fill_c1

wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

I have trial change old version Openpyxl but no affect

Comment: Filling bgcolour may not result in the colour you expect but all 3 cells should be filled. What happens? No fill for any cell?  btw the brackets around the cell values is not necessary ie `cell.value = ('A1')` need only be `cell.value = 'A1'`

Comment: It's for sure, I open right file, cell
I have tried to remove brackets but still :(

Comment: Not sure what your comment means.